# Swing's "mainloop" in Clojure

Tags: java, swing, clojure

I was writing the following piece of code (http://ideone.com/KO3gwU) to practice using the Swing in Clojure and to build a tiny little Graphical REPL.

It works fine, but there is this question bugging me. How does the code
start a "mainloop" to look out for events? I don't even call any explicit
function to start a mainloop (like the one in python Tk). My last line
simply adds an action listener to a (useless) button.

```
(.addActionListener exec act)
```

I'm new to the workings of Swing and Clojure, so an easy explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: It's started automatically for you, when the first "event" is posted to the Event Queue

Comment: Thanks! But why does it even wait for the first event?

Comment: Because not every Java project is UI based project

Comment: No, what I mean was, why doesn't the program finish execution and stop without waiting for the first event? Can you please detail on the mechanism? Anyway, thanks for the response! :)

Comment: Okay, the JVM will exit when the only running threads daemon threads, the event dispatching thread is not a daemon thread, so it won't let the JVM exit (until the last window is closed or system.exit is called)